# Developing Apps for Microsoft Surface SDK 2.0 for Third-party Device

Tags: opengl, windows-8.1, multi-touch, pixelsense, nui

I need to write applications with NUI for multiple simultaneous users. I have the following options:

1. OpenGL
2. Microsoft Surface SDK
3. Microsoft Windows 8.1 RT

Of the above three options I believe that with OpenGL I can write my programs, but I am confused about the other two.

With Microsoft Surface SDK 2.0 I am unable to confirm that it can be used with third-party multitouch enabled devices with are Windows 7/8 ready. And also will the application only run on Windows 7 platform, or will it also run on Windows 8.x platform too? How will I be able to deploy Microsoft Surface SDK 2.0 application on the third-party device?

Microsoft Windows 8.1 RT does support multitouch gestures but I can't find anything concrete on its limitations of the number of simultaneous touches.

So I would like help on getting more info on writing Microsoft SDK 2.0 application for third-party devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Surface 2.0 SDK is essentially a set of DLLs that you reference and deploy with your app.  They will work on Win7, 8, and 8.1.  They are for building 'desktop' apps though as opposed to 'modern' apps which play nicely with things in Win8 like swiping to switch apps.

Comment: And can I also leverage the power of multi-user multi-touch gesture of Surface SDK 2.0 in the apps written for Win 7/8.x too?

Comment: Surface 2.0 SDK is basically going to give you a bunch of WPF controls that are touch-friendly and support multiple users.  If you just want the basic 'gesture' APIs, those 'manipulation' events are built into WPF 4 (taken out of the Surface 1.0 SDK) and also built into the 'modern' Win8 UI frameworks.  The controls in the Win8 UI frameworks are touch-friendly but not for multiuser (you can't press 2 buttons at the same time, for example)

Comment: Thank you Robert! Your answers were of great help, and now I'd need to go forward with using Surface SDK 2.0 as I need to leverage its multiuser features.